Gradle sync replaceTokens: how to specify file encoding UTF-8?
Gradle sync replaceTokens for UTF-8 files:
 task syncFiles(type: Sync) {
        from("/path")
        into "/path2"

        filesMatching (['**/*.xml']) {
              filter(ReplaceTokens,  tokens: [version: '1.0'])
        }
  }

The output of UTF-8 files were corrupted. How to specify file encoding?

Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share (sanitized if necessary): 1st input example, 2nd expected output example, and 3rd corrupted output example.
